# Get all anchors inside specific div with regex

Tags: regex

I'm using [80legs](http://80legs.com/) to crawl the web for certain information. The information needed is specified in 80legs with regex. So for example, if I just need to parse images on my url list, I specify `<img.*?>`.

Now I also need to grab any anchors inside a div which has class "rellink relarticle mainarticle" . For example:

```
<div class="rellink relarticle mainarticle">Main articles: <a href="/wiki/Theophrastus"   title="Theophrastus">Theophrastus</a> and <a href="/wiki/Historia_Plantarum" title="Historia Plantarum">Historia Plantarum</a></div>
```

I tried adding

```
<div class="rellink relarticle mainarticle">.*?<a.*?>
```

but that only grabs the first anchor inside the div, even when there's more than one. Is it possible to change this code to grab all anchors inside the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div class="rellink relarticle mainarticle">.*?<a.*?>` matches the div's opening tag followed by any number of characters followed by **an** anchor. So use

```
<div class="rellink relarticle mainarticle">.*?(<a.*?>)+
```

instead.

Comment: Naveed, I tried it but it didn't work. I'm wondering if maybe it's because there are some other characters between the anchors? See the updated question.

Comment: @Phil `<div class="rellink relarticle mainarticle">(.*?(<a.*?>.*</a>)+.*?)+` matches the whole div. Is it the required one?